# GDPR-compatible hosted webapp to create survey

Tags: privacy, survey

I am in the process of creating a screener survey before my interview.

I would like to know what online software is available, preferably for free to create a screener survey? I could create a form myself, for example in WordPress and store the details myself that way, but wondered what other tools are available.

In terms of consent:

- I will need to add some terms of use.
- Must have a GDPR option.

For the screener I would probably be having around 10-15 questions.

Answer (score 1):

Google / Microsoft forms and SurveyMonkey may fulfill your need. These can be embedded within another page too.

Comment: Thank you for the options. Do any of these store the data inputted anywhere or are they just submitted via email?

Comment: Please choose a single product (since there is already a detailed answer about SurveyMonkey I suggest focusing on either Google or Microsoft's offering) and add a link, a screenshot. Then you must show that it complies with GDPR.

Answer (score 1):

Lime Survey seems to meet your requirements.

You can use their SaaS Offering https://www.limesurvey.org/en/ which is GDPR Compliant https://www.limesurvey.org/en/privacy-policy

Lime Survey is an Open Source Project, so you can also run your own instance of it: https://github.com/LimeSurvey/LimeSurvey

You can find the documentation to setup your own instance and more here: https://manual.limesurvey.org/

Answer (score 0):

Survey monkey is one I've used a lot and it's very powerful and flexible.  The free version allows you to view only the first 40 responses, though there's no limit to the number you can collect.  One of the other limitations is that you can not display your own branding on the survey with the free version.

It works equally well on desktop as mobile and they give you a number of theme templates to choose from, which can then also be customized to some extent.

All the data is stored on survey monkey servers and you can log into your survey monkey dashboard at any time to analyze the results.  They will also email you once each day if you've received any responses that day, but those email will not include the responses, just a notification for you to log into your dashboard.

SurveyMonkey is GDPR compliant

https://www.surveymonkey.com/curiosity/surveymonkey-committed-to-gdpr-compliance/

Comment: Please show that it complies with GDPR. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

With [PollUnit](https://pollunit.com) you can create [GDPR and CCPA compliant surveys](https://pollunit.com/en/survey). PollUnit is a German company, all servers in Europe. You can also sign a data processing agreement online. You can add your own terms and imprints. Optionally, these must also be accepted by the participants via opt-in.

The basic features are free to use. No account needed. For the Terms and Imprint Feature you need a payed plan. Here are some example question types (all available in the free plan):

[image]

Disclosure: I work for PollUnit